# 2 SwitchButton в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет. Как сделать проверку что включены оба swhitchbutton?
По умолчанию кнопка скрыта, должна отобразится после нажатия обоих switchbutton.

Реагирует только на нажатие первой.

```
fun onClickSwitch1(view: View){
            var tswitchon1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
            var sswitch = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
            var zswitch = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch2)
            var breg = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonreg)
    
            if(sswitch.isChecked){
                checkswitch = 1
                println("Первый есть")
            }
            else{
                checkswitch = 0
            }
            if(zswitch.isChecked){
                checkswitch2 = 1
                println("Второй есть")
    
            }
    
    
    
            fun ButtonRegik(view: View){
    
                if(checkswitch == 1 && checkswitch2 == 1){
                    breg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                    println("Кнопочка?")
                }
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Затупил. Слушал функцией только первый свитч и в нем пытался все провернуть. Вот рабочий вариант если вдруг кому пригодится

```html
    fun onClickSwitch1(view: View){
        var sswitch = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
        if(sswitch.isChecked){
            checkswitch = 1
            sswitch.setClickable(false);
            println("Первый есть")
        }
        else{
            checkswitch = 0
        }
    }

    fun onClickSwitch2(view: View){
        var zswitch = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch2)
        if(zswitch.isChecked){
            checkswitch2 = 1
            zswitch.setClickable(false);
            println("Второй есть")
        }
        else{
            checkswitch2 = 0
        }
        ButtonRegik(view)
    }

    fun ButtonRegik(view: View){
        var breg = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonreg)
        if(checkswitch == 1 && checkswitch2 == 1){
            breg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            println("Кнопочка?")
        }
    }
```